# Does Firestore perform a read every time a page is built?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm designing an app with Flutter and using Firestore as my database.

I have this page which is basically taking everything from a specific collection in Firestore and listing it for the user.

I'm not yet so familiar with how things work in the Firestore side and would like to make this is optimized as possible, to avoid unnecessary database reads. My question in this situation is: will Firestore perform a read in this collection every time the user opens this screen? Or only when something in this collection changes?

Let's say the user opened this list, but then went to his profile, and after that went back to this list. If the collection didn't have any changes in the meanwhile, will there be 1 or 2 reads in the database?

Would I need to use a Stream for that to happen?

Implementation of this List in Flutter

```
FutureBuilder<List<Store>>(
  future: DatabaseService().storeList,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Loading();
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => StoreTile(store: snapshot.data[index]),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Implementation of Database stuff

```
class DatabaseService {

  // Collection reference
  final CollectionReference storeCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stores');

  // Make a store list from snapshot object
  List<Store> storeListfromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Store(
        name:         doc.data()['name']  ?? '',
        description:  doc.data()['description']  ?? '',
        image:        doc.data()['image'] ?? ''
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // Get instantaneous stores list
  Future<List<Store>> get storeList async {
    return storeListfromSnapshot(await storeCollection.get());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `get()` call will fetch the data from the server. So here since you are using `get()` on a collection and let's say you have 5 documents, then it will be 5 document read. If you enter the page again, then it will also count 5 document reads.

If you want to get data from the cache then use `snapshots()` which returns data from the cache and if there are any modification then it will return data from the server.

You can also add the parameter `GetOptions` to the `get()` method for example:

```
get(GetOptions(source : Source.cache))
```

This will always get the data from cache, ignoring the server completely.

---

You can also monitor document read here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage

Also note if you keep the firebase console open then you will get unexpected reads.